# Hook all new processes and command line arguments in Windows

Tags: windows, process, hook

I wish to know what tools my IDE runs and what command line arguments it uses.
Is there such tool that will provide such information?

I can make an app that will save all processes every second or even faster but I'm still not sure that it will hook everything. There must be some tool already that will do that work much better. Like hooking OS calls for `WinExec` or `CreateProcess(Ex)`.

Comment: To those voting to migrate to StackOverflow: He's not asking how to write an app that does this, he's looking for a preexisting utility BEFORE bothering to write one :)

Comment: Exactly. I was looking for tool and I found it. I mention what I can write myself because I was looking for tool that does that work in more advanced manner. It was superuser.com question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysinternals **[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)** can log process events, among other things. It works by monitoring Native API calls, so it'll work regardless of which library function programs use.

Comment: Thank You. Seems like exactly what I look! I am fan Mark Russinovich's apps and first I looked at Process Explorer but I was not aware of Process Monitor. Once I will get it working I will mark answer as answered.